# java.io.FileNotFoundException: db.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)

Tags: java, jsp

I have written a basic jsp code for storing and retrieving the data from db.
Before that am checking validation of user.

When i click submit button it will redirect to my jsp page.

i have written a db.properties file separately.

When i gave complete path to read properties file., program is executing fine. (Which is not best way to hard code like below).

FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\**ServiceDisplay**\db.properties");

But when i specify only "db.properties" like 
(FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("db.properties");) program is not executing i got **file not found exception**.

Please not this properties file is in current working dir only. (i.e., my db.properties file and my jsp file is under **ServiceDisplay**

I tried to changing the file name as "//db.properties", "/db.properties", "./db.properties", "\db.properties", .\db.properties, ../db.properties",  "..\db.properties" .
But still i am getting **java.io.FileNotFoundException: db.properties**

Comment: Can you add the file to your classpath?

Answer (score 0):

The file 'ServiceDisplay\db.properties' is in your resources directory, to load this file is necessary to use the `getResoursceAsStream`. Code example below:

```
 ServletContext context = request.getSession().getServletContext();
 InputStream is = context.getResourceAsStream("/db.properties");
```